# Possible to get queryset from list of queryset -Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I wanted to take queryset from multiple models. I am trying to achieve multiple search with and condition.
views.py,

```
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        search_query = self.request.query_params.get('search')
        split_query = search_query.split()
        employment = None
        employee1 = []
        employment1 = []
        for query in split_query:
            print("hi", query)
        # query = self.request.query_params.get('search')
            employee = PositionFulfillment.objects.filter(
                Q(employment__employee__code__icontains=query) |
                Q(employment__employee__person__name__icontains=query) |
                Q(employment__employee__person__surname__icontains=query)
            )
            # emp = list(chain(employee))
            employee1.append(employee)
            print("employee", employee1)
            active_employee = PositionFulfillment.objects.filter(primary_flag=True, thru_date=None)
            if active_employee:
                employment = active_employee.filter(
                    Q(position__position_type__name__icontains=query) |
                    Q(employment__organization__name__icontains=query) |
                    Q(employment__status__status__employment_status__icontains=query)
                )
            employment1.append(employment)
        all_results = list(chain(map(lambda x: x, employee1), map(lambda y: y, employment1)))
        # all_results = list(chain(employee, employment))
        print("all_results", all_results)
        serializer = EmployeeSearchSerializer(all_results)

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I have got output like below,

```
all_results,
[<QuerySet [<PositionFulfillment: 27>, <PositionFulfillment: 29>, <PositionFulfillment: 30>]>, <QuerySet []>, <QuerySet []>, <QuerySet [<PositionFulfillment: 28>]>]

Expected output,
 [<PositionFulfillment: 27>, <PositionFulfillment: 29>, <PositionFulfillment: 30>]> ,<QuerySet [<PositionFulfillment: 28>]>]
```

How can i achieve this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add conditions to the query instead of creating new queries:

```
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        search_query = self.request.query_params.get('search')
        split_query = search_query.split()

        q = None  # this is filter
        for query in split_query:
            print("hi", query)
            if q is None:
                q = Q(employment__employee__code__icontains=query)
            else:
                q.add(Q(employment__employee__code__icontains=query), Q.OR)

            q.add(Q(employment__employee__person__name__icontains=query), Q.OR)
            q.add(Q(employment__employee__person__surname__icontains=query), Q.OR)

            # same for active_employee

        # make only one query based on all conditions in q
        all_results = PositionFulfillment.objects.filter(q)
        print("all_results", all_results)
        serializer = EmployeeSearchSerializer(all_results)

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: Thanks. its working fine. and find one more solutions also,  
all_results = list(chain(*employee1, *employment1)) Its also working fine

Comment: @VijiLakshmi, you also need to consider number of DB-queries. When using `list(chain(..)` I believe it will evaluate each query separately - this will do two DB queries. When conditions are combined - there will be one query which is better

Comment: okay. thanks for explaining it.

Comment: WexlerI have done what u said. But its working OR ?condition. I want to apply AND condition on mulitple search How can i do that(I want to do filter which comes from user-search)??

Comment: @VijiLakshmi, by specifying `Q.AND`: `q.add(Q(...), Q.AND)`

Comment: If i give AND there it will not work. What i want means, split_query=['front'], It will filter where front is available,  when i give split=['front','back'] it will filter both front and back available. How can i achieve???

Comment: @VijiLakshmi, this is actually `OR`. If Both `front` or `back` available

Comment: Yes. but I want AND condition.